# Trying to display numbers user entered from Array

Tags: java, arrays, double, average, user-input

Now I looked through many other questions to find similar to mine but for some reason I don't understand how to get the array the user entered to display when calculating the average. If there is a question similar to mine, please send me the link that way I can refer to it. Thank you so much. I want it to show:

*"Please enter 5 integers: 25 43 12 5 7"*

*"You have entered: 25 43 12 5 7 and the average is __"*

```
public class CalcAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {       

        double [] userinput = getArrayInfo();
        double average = CalculateAvg(userinput);
        getAvg(userinput, average);

    }

    public static double[] getArrayInfo() {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 5;
     double[] userinput =new double[NUM_ELEMENTS];
     int i = 0;

     System.out.println("Please enter 5 integers: ");
      for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i) {         
         userinput[i] = in.nextDouble();
      }     

     return userinput;
    }   

    public static double CalculateAvg(double[] userinput) {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < userinput.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + userinput[i];        
    }        
        average = sum / userinput.length;

       return average;
    }

    public static void getAvg(double[] userinput, double average) {
       int i = 0;
      System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + userinput + " is " +average);  
    }
}
```

Comment: may help you : [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: ^ Yes, but simplest way to print a Java array (`Arrays.toString(array)`) would put in commas and the brackets, which isn't the format he wants the array in.

Answer (score 1):

To produce a `String` showing an array in the way you want, probably create a method to do all the String operations for you (and not repeat your code). Create the `String` using a `StringBuilder` by iterating through the array with a for loop.

```
public String arrayToString(double[] input) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  // declare this outside of the loop
    for (double dub : input) {
        builder.append(dub + " ");
    }

    return builder.toString().trim();  // get rid of trailing spaces
}
```

Then, to implement this, change the line `System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + userinput + " is " +average)` to `System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + arrayToString(userinput) + " is " + average)`.

Also, `CalculateAvg()`, following naming conventions, would be `calculateAvg()`. You can also iterate through the for loop using the 'enhanced for loop' with `int x : userinput` instead of the counting variables you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

All classes inherits from Object and has therefore a toString() method. When you try to print the array, it calls the toString() method that returns the object's class name representation and then "@" followed by its hashcode.

A solution would be:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Or loop through the elements to print them one by one.